# mysql ERROR 29 (HY000) How to fix it please

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I have the problem : ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/home/filip/Desktop/zkouska.csv' not found (Errcode: 13) I have the .csv file on my Desktop (/home/filip/Desktop/zkouska.csv) but I really don't know how to load this file to my table. Created table has same columns. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you mention the query you are trying to execute? I presume you are trying to use `LOAD INFILE ...`. I suspect you might be having a problem either with a.) the location of the file or b.) with the privileges of the user.

Comment: I am using LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/filip/Desktop/zkouska.csv' INTO TABLE VCF COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t' IGNORE 1 LINES;. It is not problem with the location of the the file, but problem is with the privileges of the user. But I don't know, how can I get the privileges

Comment: Can you confirm if the MySQL server is running from the same machine which you are trying to load the data from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you post the error code 13:

```
[mysql@even ~]$ perror 13
OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

May you lack the permission of /home/filip/Desktop/zkouska.csv ?

please check

best wishes!

Comment: How can I get the permission pls? And need I create my own account for the permission?

Comment: I think the permission contain 2 concepts:1)with chmod command to mysql user can read 2) in MySQL db,LOAD DATA INFILE,you need FILE permission

Answer (score 3):

The LOCAL workaround option is no longer supported in most versions of MYSQL. In Ubuntu 14.04 and MYSQL 5.5 I moved the file to the /tmp directory and changed ownership of the file to mysql using the following in the shell:

```
sudo chown mysql.mysql <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a linux system make sure the file is owned by the user under which Mysql is running. Normally it's a user called mysql.